# TFS CI build trigger not triggering for SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, tfs, continuous-integration, visualsvn-server

I am attempting to use TFS for autobuilds from our Subversion repository hosted on-site with a VisualSVN server.

In TFS, I have a build configuration for "ePermit Service" which I can manually queue and run. Scheduled builds run just fine. But the Continuous Integration trigger is not firing. I was able to verify the CI Trigger would fire for a git repo hosted on the TFS server, but there is not currently support for us to move from svn to git.

According to the Event Viewer log, no changes are being detected when the repo is polled despite the Trigger's path filter including the directory (branch) the changes are being made in. Here is an abridged piece of one of the polling entries:

```
 -UserData
   - JobAgentHistory
     Plugin          Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension
     JobName         Polling Build Job 
     Result          1 
     ResultMessage   No changes detected for definition 'ePermit Service'. 0 build(s) were queued. Batched CI: False. Starting commit: 9353. Final commit: 9360.
     ...
```

Here are pertinent screenshots of my build configuration:

Sources:
[image]

Triggers:
[image]

Any help is greatly apprecatied

Comment: Do you see anything in VisualSVN Server's log? See https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/

Comment: Apologies for the delay in reply; I was out sick. I am working with support to gain access to the logs. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: get well soon! :) You can always contact us at support@visualsvn.com for assistance.

Comment: Nothing in the VisualSVN logs appears to line up with the TFS polling logs. I've asked to have the logging level changed to "Debug" in hopes something shows up